# Image Shifts When I Click 'Print' Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have a popup that has a 'Print' button. When I click the 'Print' button it is supposed to print the popup and only the popup, not the background. Currently my code prints the `div` with the id `printableDiv`. However when it prints, it shifts my image with the id `pdf1` up like 20 px.Is there anyway to fix this? I am up for any suggestion that works, even if it means I have to replace my entire project.

Note: It also appears to do this when you run the code snippet. But it looks perfect in my browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
  
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible"); 
       $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1); 
  
       });
  
  $( ".close" ).click(function() {

       $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
       $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
});

        function printDiv()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('printableDiv').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
            win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
 document.getElementById("pdf1").style.top=117 + "px";  
        }
```

```css
    .t {
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        -moz-transform-origin: top left;
        -o-transform-origin: top left;
        -ms-transform-origin: top left;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
        -o-transform: scale(0.25);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: pre;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    #t1_1{left:256px;top:35px;letter-spacing:0.1px;}
    #t2_1{left:334px;top:87px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t3_1{left:210px;top:123px;}
    #t4_1{left:238px;top:123px;word-spacing:-0.3px;}
    #t5_1{left:210px;top:141px;}
    #t6_1{left:210px;top:160px;}
    #t7_1{left:210px;top:179px;}
    #t8_1{left:238px;top:141px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t9_1{left:238px;top:160px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ta_1{left:238px;top:179px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tb_1{left:343px;top:242px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tc_1{left:210px;top:278px;}
    #td_1{left:210px;top:297px;}
    #te_1{left:210px;top:315px;}
    #tf_1{left:210px;top:334px;}
    #tg_1{left:238px;top:278px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #th_1{left:238px;top:297px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ti_1{left:238px;top:315px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #tj_1{left:238px;top:334px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tk_1{left:286px;top:393px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tl_1{left:210px;top:429px;}
    #tm_1{left:210px;top:448px;}
    #tn_1{left:210px;top:466px;}
    #to_1{left:210px;top:485px;}
    #tp_1{left:238px;top:429px;word-spacing:-0.3px;}
    #tq_1{left:238px;top:448px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tr_1{left:238px;top:466px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ts_1{left:238px;top:485px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #tt_1{left:326px;top:544px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tu_1{left:210px;top:580px;}
    #tv_1{left:210px;top:599px;}
    #tw_1{left:210px;top:618px;}
    #tx_1{left:238px;top:618px;}
    #ty_1{left:210px;top:636px;}
    #tz_1{left:238px;top:636px;}
    #t10_1{left:210px;top:655px;}
    #t11_1{left:238px;top:580px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t12_1{left:238px;top:599px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t13_1{left:238px;top:655px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t14_1{left:264px;top:716px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t15_1{left:210px;top:752px;}
    #t16_1{left:210px;top:771px;}
    #t17_1{left:210px;top:789px;}
    #t18_1{left:210px;top:808px;}
    #t19_1{left:238px;top:752px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t1a_1{left:238px;top:771px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t1b_1{left:238px;top:789px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t1c_1{left:238px;top:808px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}

    .s1_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    }

    .s2_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    }

    .s3_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }

    .s4_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }

      .button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        border-radius: 20px/50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background: orange;
      }
      .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        transition: opacity 500ms;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        height: 578%;
        width: 117.5%;
      }
      .overlay:target {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        display:none;
      }
      .PopUp {
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 60%;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
      }
      .PopUp .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 30px;
        transition: all 200ms;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
      }
      .PopUp .close:hover {
        color: orange;
      }
      .PopUp .content {
        max-height: 117.5%;
        overflow: auto;
      }

.pdf1 {
width: 935px;
height: 1210px;
background-color: white;
-moz-transform: scale(1);
z-index: 0;
border: none;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
        <div class="PopUp">
            <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="printableDiv" id="printableDiv"></div>
<div id="p1" class=p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

   <!-- Begin page background -->
<div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img></div>
   <!-- End page background -->


<!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
<div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
<div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
<div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
<div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
<div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
<div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
<div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
<div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
<div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
<div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
<div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
<div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
<div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
<div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
<div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
<div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
<div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
<div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
<div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
<div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
<div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
<div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
<div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
<div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
<div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
<div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
<div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv()" value="Print">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#printableDiv` is empty. I'm assuming it's populated with content somewhere? And why do you have `document.getElementById("pdf1").style.top=117 + "px"; ` after `win.print()`? That also likely won't do anything if it's the only element on the page. Use `.style.marginTop = '117px'`

Comment: If it is the only element on the page, it will still move if you adjust it's top and it is not `position: static;`. He also states that printableDiv is printing and that his problem is the element with the id of pdf1 moves after printing. If you remove the line of code that moves pdf1, problem solved.

Comment: @KyleRichardson they're using `document.write()` so there will be no CSS on the page, so the `position` will be `static`. The `top: 117px` line comes **after** `win.print()` so how is removing that going to do anything to affect what prints?

Comment: @MichaelCoker, ok so even if it is after the line win.print();, all that does is open the print dialog to allow a user to print... so by the time you actually hit the print button, the image has already been shifted....

Comment: @KyleRichardson yeah you're right, and I just tested it out and put some JS in modifying page styles after calling `print()` and the styles that came after `print()` actually showed up in the print dialog. Weird, I wouldn't expect it to do that.

Comment: Been tripped up by things like that in the past myself :)

Comment: @KyleRichardson learned something new today! +1 to you

Comment: @MichaelCoker that is my goal for everyday sir!

Comment: @KyleRichardson Sorry if I was unclear but the image shifted down during the printing process in the window it creates. Therefore what is printed has the image in the wrong place.

Comment: @MichaelCoker You were right in the fact that removing the `document.getElementById("pdf1").style.top=117 + "px";` did not solve the problem. If you would like to answer you still can.

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph your demo doesn't reproduce the behavior for me. Does it reproduce it for you? I also created a pen, not seeing it https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWzrZR

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph yeah I wouldn't expect that `top` js to do anything anyways, the position of that element (`#pdf1`) is `static` so a `top` value won't do anything.

Comment: @MichaelCoker If you were to copy the code into an HTML file it would probably reproduce the behavior I'm describing. Sites like CodePen and JSFiddle don't allow some functions to work.

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph negative ghost rider, I put it on a local webserver and it doesn't work. codepen should handle the page just fine.

Comment: @MichaelCoker You tried clicking the 'Print' button and looked at what came out of the printer? Because the problem is what comes out of the printer. Not how it looks on the screen.

Comment: oh, haha, so I was right! I was arguing with @KyleRichardson about that, he thought the layout problem was on the website, and I thought it was on the printout. No I didn't print it, but I'm heading out for a little bit and will check it out when I get back if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys for your trouble. It turned out I forgot to include the following bit of code in the area to print:

`div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}`

Which caused the image to shift upwards.

Answer (score 1):

removing the following line from your code should prevent the movement.

```
document.getElementById("pdf1").style.top=117 + "px";
```

in your `printDiv()` function

Comment: that line comes after `win.print();`. how would that solve anything?

Comment: Read the question again. "However when it prints, it shifts my image with the id pdf1 up like 20 px.Is there anyway to fix this?" It will prevent that from happening.

Comment: How is removing top: 117px after the window prints going to change anything in what prints?

Comment: He never said that the image was shifted in the print... he said that when it prints, the image with the id pdf1 shifts...

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah I misread that, I thought they were saying it was shifted in what printed.

Comment: The way it's setup now, it will be shifted in the print as well unless someone can hit the print button in the print dialog that window.print() brings up before the computer executes that line of code... highly unlikely.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I removed the code but since it was after the `window.print()` function it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @MichaelCoker You were right in the fact that removing the `document.getElementById("pdf1").style.top=117 + "px";` did not solve the problem. If you would like to answer you still can.

Comment: @KyleRichardson It seems to continue to do the same in the Snippet as well even with the code removed so it can't be just me.

Comment: First off, your snippet has errors in it. Secondly, I can assure you that is why your element with the id of pdf1 is being moved.